# Xamarin: Replace Support.V4.App.Fragment within App.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library

How can I replace a frame layout in my `App.fragment` with `Support.V4.App.fragment`?

I tried:

```
FragmentManager
.BeginTransaction()
.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_scancontainer, scanFragment).Commit();
```

and

```
ChildFragmentManager
    .BeginTransaction()
    .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_scancontainer, scanFragment).Commit();
```

where `Resource.Id.fragment_scancontainer` is a frame layout in a fragment and `scanFragment` class inherits from `Android.Support.V4.App`'

Can anyone please advice ?

Comment: Don't you need to use SupportFragmentManager?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can I ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have [`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) in [`android.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) or vice versa. I'd recommend to refactor your code and have a single fragment type everywhere if possible.

In case of activities, if you need `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, the activity must extend [`FragmentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) (or better [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)) and you must use [`SupportFragmentManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()).

Comment: I resolved this issue by using mvvmcross but just curious how to resolve it without mvvmcross plugins. If I'm using third party plugin which forces to use v4 fragment then how can I use them in my app.fragment ?

Comment: Change your `android.app.Fragment ` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. That's pretty straightforward. Generally, I'd recommend to always use support fragments. As a bonus, you'll have _almost_ all the latest APIs available regardless of the SDK version.

Comment: Cool. Thank you.